# How to remove axis ticks in matplotlib line chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph using matplotlib and was trying to remove the axis ticks on all sides of the plot. I tried to use the ax.tick_params() function and set all the args to "off" but my plot still displayed them. Kindly advise.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('women bachelors.csv')
df.head()


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.Year,df.Biology, c = 'blue', label = 'Women')
ax.plot(df.Year, (100 - df.Biology), c = 'green', label = "Men")
ax.tick_params(bottom = 'off', left = 'off', right = 'off', top = 'off') # This isnt working for some reason. #LOOKINTOIT
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_title("Percentage of Biology Degrees Awarded By Gender")
ax.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

Running this code removed all the spines but as you can see it still kept the ticks. I am trying to improve the plot aesthetics by reducing chartjunk. Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Try replacing lines 10~14 by `ax.axis('off')`, does that work?

Comment: Hello  @JansthcirlU.

The code took away both the axes completely. I should have mentioned that I want to keep the actual axis values because they describe the year and percentage of awarded degrees. Just want to get rid of the tick marks themselves if that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would also need to add for which axis you need to remove the ticks for.

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',bottom=False,left=False,top=False)
```

You can find further reference to the api: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

Comment: Thank you. Worked Perfectly. I see some other places use "off" instead of "False" as the bool. Is "off" the incorrect notation?

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', 
                labelleft='off', labelbottom='off ')
```

I guess this would do.